# What happened to the the USS Franklin crew?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In ***Star Trek Beyond***, we find out that the USS Franklin is

A century old lost ship, and some of it's crew has become the main antagonists via alien technology. In the movie, we see old clips of the ships log, including one where shuttles or drop ships arrive. But many people online are saying that most of the (likely <50 complement<sup>*</sup>) crew died in a crash? I assumed that while some may have died in the crash, the majority lived (based on the ships log) at first and then their numbers dwindled for various reasons, or even that Krall killed some in using the Life Extending Technology.

What exactly happened to the crew? How did they die? And how many were there?

<sub>*Note: The NX-01 Enterprise had 83 standard crew complement, and the Franklin is similar in shape, but 2/3rds the size according to [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57164/how-does-the-uss-franklin-fit-in-the-pre-kelvin-timeline/57414#comment90565_57170) comment.</sub>

Comment: My interpretation was that they died of "natural causes" (in which I will include accidents, falls, animal attacks, illness, old age, starvation, hypothermia, etc.) In other words: nothing special, they "just died".

Comment: @Jorg that's why I expected, but many people are saying they died on crash arrival. So basically I'm looking for word of God evidence.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was that Edison/Krall used the alien tech on the planet to suck the life from the Federation crew members of the Franklin to prolong his life and those of his followers like Manas and Kalara (who I presume were fellow soldiers).

Comment: You are correct. Krall Memory Alpha (wiki) also states this: On Altamid, Edison found technology left behind by a previous civilization, including Swarm ships, a drone workforce, and an energy transference process that allowed him to "drain" other individuals to prolong his own life. Using their newly-acquired Swarm, Edison, Le, and Wolff captured scores of alien ships and drained their crews to survive, which also mutated their biology to resemble that of their victims. In time, Edison became "Krall", suppressing much of his Human identity and ceasing to speak in English."